# MVVM Silverlight Framework Choices

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Which Silverlight MVVM Frameworks should I look at - taking into account these areas of functionality.

1) IoC - can I choose my own? I would like to avoid using MEF w/ Attributes.
2) Navigation
3) Callback simplification
4) "IMessageBox" type abstractions
5) Testability
6) Logging

Note: mitigating a conversion to full-blown WPF is not a concern. This app will always be only Silverlight.

What other things haven't I thought of?

Any good online references that compare and contrast the current frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), but you can find a comprehensive list of many frameworks/libraries with features comparison [here](http://www.japf.fr/silverlight/mvvm/).

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 3):

[PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (this is the mainpage). Here is some [information](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-silverlight/) about what it offers. Here is what Microsoft has to [say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943055.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick side note, I know this doesn't answer your question and so on.

Someone (Josh Smith) once [said](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/the-mvvm-twilight-zone/) that MVVM has nothing to do with IoC; so any MVVM framework that forces you to use a specific IoC framework does something wrong in my opinion.

Also, testability is innate to MVVM but only if you do your job of structuring your Model and ViewModel accordingly. So a MVVM framework should never restrict this, it's all up to you.